# How to determine the number of cards per row using bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, next.js

I have a question here about creating rows and columns.
I need to add 4 cards per row. And I might have N cards.

My question is:
Do I need to have a

```
<div className="row">
```

for every single row? Or can I have a single row that encapsulates all the

```
<div className='col-sm-3'>
```

?
From my understanding, when I use col-sm-3, I'm already saying that I'll have 4 cards per row (4 x 3 = 12).

Problem is when I use only one row to encapsulate everything it works fine.
But I'm not sure about the right approach to it. Is that right? 
Should I have 1 `<div className="row">` for every 4 columns? Or is it ok to have 20 cards in just one row?
When I try having 1 row for every 4 columns it's breaking the code and it's not working properly.
It displays the whole thing, but for for a fraciton of a second, then it blinks and everything disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Bootstrap documentation for more in depth explanation. As far as I understand your question, div class=“row” and inside this class you put your col-classes. So only one row is needed.